# Handling multiple bluetooth connections through services

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an application where an android phone is a bluetooth Server that accepts bluetooth connections and later uses them to send and receive data to other phones.

My idea was to use a BluetoothAdapter and react to the ACTION_FOUND intent by starting a service. However, I don't see how I can stay connected to the Services that get created this way. I put the following into the AndroidManifest file:

```
<service
      android:label="@string/bluetooth_connection_activity"
      android:name=".BluetoothConnection" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND" />  
      </intent-filter>   
  </service>
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Is my assumption right that by now, every time a device is found, a new service is created? If yes, how can I keep connected to this service so I can use the bluetooth connection?

If you think I am doing this completely the wrong way, please also tell me.

Comment: Are you sure you can have multiple bt connections?

Comment: Macarse : Yes you can, I did an application that did it. However I don't know how many (it was a 3 players game)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ACTION_FOUND` in BroadcastReceiver for discovering BT devices.

```
mBT = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBT.getBoundedDevices();
if (pairedDevices.size()>0) {
    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        device.getName();
        device.getAddress();
    }
}
```

OR:

create BroadcastReceiver and mBT.startDiscovery();
see
1) "Android in Action" page 367
2) "Android SDK" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html
3) sample BluetoothChat in Android-SDK http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html